# Temporizados em laço while

Tags: php

Olá

Eu tenho um laço while em PHP, eu gostaria de rodar o laço while 1 vez a cada 20 segundos, tem como ?

Obrigado

Comment: tentou usar `sleep()`? ou não resolve o seu problema?

Comment: E as palavras foram confusas. Você quer executar um laço `while` inteiro a cada 20s ou cada iteração do laço deve ser feita nesse tempo?

Comment: Então eu quero que rode 1 vez o laço while dai para e aguarda 20 segundos dai roda de novo e assim por diante

Answer (score 0):

Deixe esse arquivo rodando em um Cron e sete ele pra executar 20 em 20 segundos

Comment: Qual arquivo ??

Comment: Esse seu script está em um arquivo .php não é?   coloca ele no cron do seu servidor

Answer (score -2):

Assim resolve seu problema:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    sleep(20000);
}
```